# Check label found in modal had a specific status

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have to validate that when I click on the button submit a popup opens with a specific label. The label which will show has to have a specific status.
For example:This is the button submit html
`<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">submit</button>`

When I click on the button, another modal will open with a label on top of it.
The label which will open in the modal should have the status positive
[image]

"abc" can be the label and "positive" is the status. All these are on a table. Basically, if the modal opens and has the label abc, this means that abc had the status positive

This is what I have done so far:

```
cy.get('.btn').and('have.class', 'btn-primary').contains('submit').click()
cy.get('.form-header').should('contain.text', 'abc')
cy.get('.close-modal').click()
cy.contains('td', 'abc...').scrollIntoView()
cy.get('.badge-label').and('contain.text', 'positive').should('be.visible')
```

This is not good as I am checking that the label has the status. I want to check that the label found in the modal after clicking on submit has the status positive. Please do let me know if any other info is required.
Thank you

Comment: Can you show the html where i can see both the label and the status ?

Comment: Its in the image above or you need something else :)
abc is the label and positive is the status

Comment: The text abc and label positive are inside one tr. And now you have to first find abc text and then validate that its label is positive ?

Comment: What i want to check that when the modal opens the label it is showing has the status positive. Does it mean the same thing as you said?
because the modal opens first then we get the label inside it. so the modal should have next label with status positive

Comment: I am not sure that is why I wanted to see the entire HTML. Is your webpage public?

Comment: No it is not public but if you need any other info you can let me know

Answer (score 1):

Usually a modal is a separate block of code in the DOM, appended to the end of the page after you click your submit button.

So, you'd have to find something unique on that modal. It looks like you tried with these lines

```js
cy.get('.form-header').should('contain.text', 'abc')
cy.get('.close-modal').click()
```

What you need to do now is manually inspect in chrome devtools

- in normal browser, clikc open the model
- open devtool, scroll down to the bottom to find the block for modal
- or right-click the modal to take you there
- identify the elements with the status

Maybe you will end up with something like

```js
cy.get('.form-header').should('contain.text', 'abc')
cy.get('.badge-label').should('contain.text', 'positive')  // here cehck status in modal
cy.get('.close-modal').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you:

```js
cy.get('.btn').and('have.class', 'btn-primary').contains('submit').click()
cy.get('.form-header').should('contain.text', 'abc')
cy.contains('td', 'abc')
  .parent('tr')
  .within(() => {
    cy.get('div.badge-label').should('include.text', 'positive')
  })
```

Comment: I was more like looking for a way for it to know here itself that it has status positive as it has been shown in the modal
```cy.get('.btn').and('have.class', 'btn-primary').contains('submit').click()
cy.get('.form-header').should('contain.text', 'abc')``` 
and then i will close the modal..

Comment: I have updated my answer.